# Batch file that deletes folders of users in C:\users that are more than 210 days

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that removes/deletes different user(s) folders in C:\users that are older than 210 days.

I tried this
forfiles /p C:\users /d -210 /c "cmd /c del @file"

However this command deletes the shortcut of the current user as well as those shortcuts are older than 210 days.

Can I get the batch file to only remove the entire folder if the last modified date of the content is older 210 days

Also can I specify the starting name of the folder to be deleted(the users starts with PDC), as I fear it may delete some of the important hidden document of a computer, as this batch file will be run on an administrator account.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Any reason why this has to be a batch file and not a powershell or vbscript? Also, simply deleting the user profile folder will not remove any user profile settings in the registry for newer versions of Windows (8+ I believe...but may also be true for Windows 7...)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The purpose for deleting the user folders is for space purposes, as the computer is shared and constantly used replacing the disk is not an option due to certain restrictions as well.

Comment: It's due to the environment that batch file is preferred.

Comment: Replacing the disk isn't an option, but you risk registry corruption by deleting the folders without removing the references in the registry. Can the batch file call a [VBScript](http://superuser.com/questions/643417/delete-user-profile-from-command-line-windows-7)/[Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-Unused-user-4047f41d) script to properly remove the profile so the chance of disk replacement/reimage is lowered? If not, `wmic /node:"localhost" path win32_UserProfile where LocalPath="c:\\users\\PDC*" Delete 2>>c:\temp\wmic.err Delete` might do what you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run robocopy in list-only mode and if there were no files newer than the specified age proceed with the actual delete operation:

```
@echo off
set AGE=2
set EXCLUDE="Public" "admin1" "admin2"
for /d %%D in (C:\users\*) do (
    echo %EXCLUDE% | find /i """%%~nD""" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        set too_new=0
        robocopy "%%D" "%%D" /L /v /s /xjd /minage:%AGE% | findstr /r /c:"^. *too new" >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo Deleting %AGE% days old %%D
            rd /s /q "%%D"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

> Don't forget to do a test run first by commenting out the `rd` line: put `rem` and a space before it.

Notes:

- `/L` = list-only mode, no copying performed
- `/V` = verbose mode, report files skipped for various reasons, e.g. the "too new" we look for
- `/S` = look in subdirectories
- `/xjd` = don't follow junction points for directories, useful if those point to an unavailable device
- `^. *too new` regular expression in findstr lists lines beginning with a tab character followed by lots of spaces and then `too new`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions it works like what I needed when tested on other folders. I believe this would also delete the public folder, is there a way I can prevent that? Thanks again

Comment: If I want to exclude another folder with a certain name admin1, admin2 etc should I set the different naming? Than add && "%%D" =="%set name%"?